# How to select video from gallery and crop/resize it just like image cropping in android

Tags: java, android, video, crop

How to select video from gallery and crop/resize it  just like image cropping in android. I am searching it for last two days. But i didnt find any samples or example. If you have any idea or samples, pls suggest me.

Thank You.

Comment: Its a nice question up there .... guyz dont freak answer...boom oops

Comment: Is there any chance to do it?

Comment: I am still searching it. I couldn't find samples or example. But i found working app in Google Play. [click link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaushal.androidstudio&hl=en)

Comment: @ramkumar5035: have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

On android 4.0 + you can use [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html)

Basic idea is to use Matrix  object.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);
mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
```

Full article available [here](http://goo.gl/WAikcl).

Comment: In the above article the video is Zooming but how can I crop the video and save it to the local storage?I am using ffmpeg to crop the video.I am also panning the landscape video .I want only the video portion which is visible